# Log in console after install Docker on RedHat (Azure)

Tags: azure, docker, logging, console, redhat

After install Docker 18.x on RedHat 7.5 (hosted at Azure), some process is writing the log below to console each 1 minute. How do I disable it, please? Thanx for all!

`INFO ExtHandler Updated NIC state
[
    {
        "name": "lo",
        "link": " mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\"
        "link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 "
        "numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 "
    }, 
    {
        "name": "docker0",
        "link": " mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default \"
        "    link/ether 02:42:7d:f0:24:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 \    bridge forward_delay 1500 hello_time "
        "200 max_age 2000 ageing_time 30000 stp_state 0 priority 32768 vlan_filtering 0 vlan_protocol 802.1Q bridge_id "
        "8000.2:42:7d:f0:24:58 designated_root 8000.2:42:7d:f0:24:58 root_port 0 root_path_cost 0 topology_change 0 "
        "topology_change_detected 0 hello_timer    0.00 tcn_timer    0.00 topology_change_timer    0.00 gc_timer   "
        "16.78 vlan_default_pvid 1 vlan_stats_enabled 0 group_fwd_mask 0 group_address 01:80:c2:00:00:00 mcast_snooping "
        "1 mcast_router 1 mcast_query_use_ifaddr 0 mcast_querier 0 mcast_hash_elasticity 4 mcast_hash_max 512 "
        "mcast_last_member_count 2 mcast_startup_query_count 2 mcast_last_member_interval 100 mcast_membership_interval "
        "26000 mcast_querier_interval 25500 mcast_query_interval 12500 mcast_query_response_interval 1000 mcast_startup_query_interval "
        "3125 mcast_stats_enabled 0 mcast_igmp_version2 mcast_mld_version 1 nf_call_iptables 0 nf_call_ip6tables 0 nf_call_arptables 0 "
        "addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 "
    }, 
    {
        "name": "eth0",
        "link": " mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    "
        "link/ether 00:0d:3a:11:4e:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 64 numrxqueues 
        ""64 gso_max_size 62780 gso_max_segs 65535 "
    }
]`

Comment: Which process? Did u identify it?

Comment: Not again. But today, I started the machine on Azure and the problem do not happens. So, when I restarted the Docker daemon, it returns:
`$ sudo systemctl restart docker`

`TECH PREVIEW: Overlay filesystem may not be fully supported.`

`Please review provided documentation for limitations.`

`Bridge firewalling registered`

`ctnetlink v0.93: registering with nfnetlink.`

`IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready`

`2018/09/17 10:36:24.147252 **...another big json...**`

`2018/09/17 10:36:24.385188 **...same problematic big json...**`